# What is the origin of "depperter"

Tags: etymology, phonetics, bavarian

On the surface, the Austrian appellative *Depperter*, adj. *bist' deppert?*, also Upper German appellative *Du Depp* “You idiot” may be correlated with *zerdeppern* “to break pots etc.”.

Pfeifer traces two different origins, an Upper German one akin to *tappen* “step, touch”, *onomatopoeia* ("lautnachahmend"), the other from Upper Saxon and akin to *Topf* “pot”.

<sub>https://www.dwds.de/wb/Depp</sub>
<sub>https://www.dwds.de/wb/zerdeppern</sub>

Bayerisches Wörterbuch *-deppern* s.v. *-deppen* (col. 3.1569-70) suggests Old High German *bidebben*, Middle High German *biteben*, “wohl zur selben Wz. wie *tappen*”, whereas *Depp* (col. 3.1566-7) suggests *tappen*², cf. col. 3.1217f. *tappen* 1. “gehen”, 2. “treten, auftreten” and more.

<sub>https://publikationen.badw.de/de/bwb/-/3.1217.pdf</sub>
<sub>https://publikationen.badw.de/de/bwb/-/3.1219.pdf</sub>
<sub>https://publikationen.badw.de/de/bwb/-/3.1565.pdf</sub>
<sub>https://publikationen.badw.de/de/bwb/-/3.1567.pdf</sub>
<sub>https://publikationen.badw.de/de/bwb/-/3.1569.pdf</sub>

Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Althochdeutschen: *bidebben* “un-
terdrücken, betäuben, einschläfern, *opprimere, retudere, sopire*” reconstruct Proto-Germanic **þabjan-*, cp. Old Icelandic *þefja* “zerstoßen, stampfen (von Grütze)”, though they initially note confusion with *dempfen* and eventually a similar case with Sanskrit *tápati*, cp. OHG *de-ba*. This would impliy Proto-Indo-European **tap* or **tep-*, respectively.

> Die einzige formal genau entsprechende Bil-dung in den germ. Sprachen ist aisl. *þefja* sw. v. ‚zerstoßen, stampfen (von Grütze)‘ < urgerm. **þajan-*. Auf die gleiche Wz. urgerm. **þaf-* (s. u.) gehen zurück: nnorw. *tava* ‚reißen,
> schleppen‘; vgl. ndän. *tave* ‚Faser‘, ält. ndän. ‚Büschel Flachs, Wolle‘; nschwed. dial. *tav*, nnorw. dial. tave ‚kleines, zerfasertes Stück,
> Tuch‘; nnorw. *tafs(e)*, nschwed. *tafs* ‚kleiner zu-
> sammengewickelter Haufe, Wisch‘, ndän. *tjavs*
> ‚Zotte‘ (mit eingeschobenem *j* als spontane Pa-latalisierung bei verächtlichen Ausdrücken; da-zu Lühr, Expressivität 87 f.). Sofern anord. *þǫf-ta* sw. v. ‚schlagen, stampfen‘ (< **þafutōn / þa-
> utōn-*) zu aisl. *þefja* gehört, kann auch nost-fries. *dafen, daven* ‚klopfen, stampfen‘ von der diesen Verben zugrundeliegenden Wz. abgelei-
> tet sein. Im Ablautverhältnis stehen: anord. *þœ-fa* sw. v. ‚walken, stampfen‘ < **þōijan-*; *þóf* n.
> ‚Gedränge, Streit, Zank‘, *þófi* m. ‚Filz‘ (woraus
> möglicherweise lit. *tūbà, tbas*, lett. *tūba*,
> apreuß. *tubo* ‚Filz‘; s. Trautmann, Apreuß.
> Sprach.denkm. 451; dagegen Fraenkel, Lit. et.
> Wb. 1134: unsicher).

<sub>(Albert L. Lloyd, Rosemarie Lühr, Otto Springer. Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Althochdeutschen II. Vandenhoeck & Ruprecht, 1998. (ISBN 978-3-525-20768-0). s. v. 'bidebben'. (https://ewa.saw-leipzig.de/articles/bidebben))</sub>

Nothing in this is informative for *deppert*, at all. That's *out of the question.*

The various connotations in Bayerisches Wörterbuch, which see, might work with bleached semantics, but what they were thinking is not clear to me.

So what is it really?

Comment: @vectory As you already wrote in your question, *deppert* is the adjective. *Depperter* is the nominative masculine singular strong form of *deppert*. So *deppert* is the base form. What you wrote in your previous remarks is only confusing and misleading.

Comment: *Deppert* is just an adjective derived from *Depp* with a suffix (see https://publikationen.badw.de/de/bwb/index#9678); *bedeppe(r)n* is irrelevant, as is *zerdeppern*.

Comment: Aus welchem Grund formatierst Du die Links so, dass man sie nicht qua Klick aufrufen kann? Findest Du das so schick, diese winzige Schrift? Wieso keine Liste? Sicher kann man alles drei haben - probier es aus!

Comment: @RHa: actually "Depp" is the base form, the "-ert" suffix is similar to High German "-lich" or "-ig" - a marker for *Adjektiva* and *Adverbien* derived from other words. Verbatim "deppert" means "(to behave) like a 'Depp'". "Depperter" is a form of this *Adjektiv* where the *Nomen* is left out. In High German you can similarily say "ein Dummer", which is short for "ein dummer Mann", "ein dummer Junge", etc..

Comment: @bakunin and vectory: Please take a break from this conversation. This kind of language and tone is not accepted here. This applies to comments from both of you.

Comment: The translation of "Du Depp" by "du Idiot" is wrong. "Idiot" came into the German language in the 17th century from English, where, since the 14th century, it meant a permanent mental incapacity. The English didn't get it from the (original) Greek either but from French *idiote*, who in turn got it from Latin *idiota*. The Romans got it from the Greek. *ἰδιώτης* meant a citizen not holding a state office, the opposite of a state official. The lowest rank in the Athenian army was called *ἰδιώτης*, which there meant "untrained fighter". A modern translation of the term would be "layman".

Comment: "Mental incapacity" and everything it entails is well within the meaning of "idiot" (which, not long ago, was used in medicine alike, not only as an - metonymous - insult), but all that is "Depp" exactly not. In fact, "Depp" encompasses things like "to be slow on the uptake" and the like - quite contrary to what "Idiot" stands for. An "idiot" is not "slow" but rather "unable" when it comes to mental processes. To be an "idiot" is also a congenital state whereas one can "become *deppert*".

Comment: "ἰδιώτης" is a noun derived from "ἴδιος", an adjective meaning "private, personal". The opposite would be "public, common". It is derived from the PIE root \*swe(d) which many indoeuropean languages took up: "swes" (Gotic, "personal"), "suus" (Latin, "his") but also "Schwester", "Schwager", "Schwieger-".

Answer (score 7):

In the Bavarian language/dialect there are many adjectives, that end in *-ert:*

- *[schlampert](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schlampert)* = schlampig (sloppy)
- *[hatschert](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hatschert)* = hinkend (limping), von *[hatschen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hatschen)* = schwerfällig gehen oder eine lange Strecke gehen
- *[goschert](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/goschert)* sein = frech und ausfällig daherreden (talk cheekily and abusively) (Goschn = Mund, Mundhöhle, manchmal auch Kiefer)
- *scheckert* = gescheckt; ein unregelmäßiges Muster haben
- *gugerscheckert* = Sommersprossen habend (Gugerschecken = Sommersprossen)
- *bunkert* (auch *punkert*) = einen kompakten Körperbau habend (klein und dick)
- *[dalkert](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dalkert)* = ungeschickt und dumm
- *glatzert* = kahlköpfing (von *Glatze*)
- *[graupert](https://www.ostarrichi.org/wort/979/graupert)* = zerzaust (Frisur)
- *großkopfert* = überheblich und herablassend
- *halbert* = halb
- *hoppertatschert* (auch: *hoppertatschig*) = ungeschickt
- *[letschert](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/letschert)* = schlapp, verwelkt
- *luckert* = löchrig
- *zahnluckert* = ein unvollständiges Gebiss habend
- *[nackert](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nackert)* = nackt
- *pudelnackert* = völlig nackt
- *[patschert](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/patschert)* (auch: *potschert*) = ungeschickt (clumsy like a *Patsch* = clumsy person)
- *patzert* = patzig, rüpelhaft (stroppy, snotty)
- *pickert* = klebrig
- *spinnert* = verrückt
- *tramhapert* = dusselig, noch halb schlafend
- *wampert* = einen dicken Bauch habend (Wampe = dicker Bauch)
- *wurlert* = unruhig, nervös (Verb "wurln" = wuseln, krabbeln)
- *zerlempert* = verschlissen, aus den Fugen geraten

And *[deppert](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/deppert)* is just one of them. It means *dorky* or *stupid* like a *Depp.* And the etymology of the noun *Depp* (which means *idiot*) was given already in your question.

---

### Depperter

Many of the adjectives listed above can be used to describe persons (*der glatzerte Mann, die zahnluckerte Frau, etc.*). And nominalization of adjectives works in Bavarian dialect/language the same as in German. So, you can use the nominalized form to name a person, as is done in these examples:

- Wos macht a **Nackerter** im Hawelka?
  Was macht ein Nackerter im Hawelka?
  *»Hawelka«* ist the name of a famous café in the center of Vienna. This sentence is from the lyrics of the Viennese dialect song *Jö schau* by Georg Danzer ([video with lyrics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23mlQX9MlO4))
- Da **Wamperte,** da **Glotzerte** und I.
  Der Wamperte, der Glatzerte und ich.
  Title of another Viennese dialect song, sung by Marianne Mendt and Wolfgang Ambros, written by Georg Danzer. [Lyrics](https://www.georgdanzer.at/lieder/da-wamperte-da-glatzerte-und-i-fuer-marianne-mendt/) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9N8JDlwjC0)
- **Großkopferte** sind auch nur Menschen.
  Title of a portrait of a person. [Quelle](https://www.meine-anzeigenzeitung.de/lokales/hallertau/grosskopferte-sind-auch-menschen-2614577.html).

And so, *»ein Depperter«* is just a person who is *deppert,* i.e the same as a *Depp.* (While *Depp* refers more to a person who is an idiot, *Depperter* refers more to person who does idiotic things, so the difference is very subtile.)

Comment: prove that it's "just" one of them. Just how just is "just" really? There was no etymology in Question. "*tappen²*” is not provable or falsifiable in face of homonyms (in particular, I saw one sense somewhere in those pages that is equivalent to *Dämpfer*).

Comment: @vectory: I don't how what you are expecting that a proof might look like, so I added some more of these adjectives.

Comment: What I expect doesn't matter. You are clearly speculating based on grammar judgement without giving any etymological information beyond the surface analysis.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: "gugascheckert" is from "gugascheckn" - Sommersprossen, also I'd like to add: "feichtlat" (Feuchtigkeit an sich habend, zB Räume), "rearat" = verweint, heulend (von "rear'n" - weinen, heulen), "fleckat" = von Flecken übersät, "stierlat" = wörtl. "stierig", das Analogon zu "läufig" bei Kühen, im übertragenen Sinne auf Frauen angewandt, "p°ampat" = ungehobelt, rüde, herablassend

Comment: Did you mean: Frankish *schockiert* (red in the face, blushed, embarassed)? Or English *checkered*, from *checkers*?

Comment: @bakunin: You are absolutely right about *Gugerschecken.* I corrected this. (The word *Gugerschecken* was not used very often in the region I grew up.) - Yes, I know there are much more adjectives (and also participles) that end in *-ert* (or *-at* if you prefer this spelling), but I think the list is still long enough.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: dialects are usually spoken, not written. This is why there is - unlike with High German - no commonly accepted way of spelling something. I agree with you that the spoken suffix "-at" would probably have a (hypothetical) analogue "-ert", but since there is no commonly acknowledged way of transcribing dialect I tend to go with the spoken, which (to my knowledge) is to replace "-er-" by "-a-" and "-ert" by "-at". Hence "gug-A-scheck-AT". Also, the "e" in "-en" is usually dropped, hence "-scheckn" instead of "-schecken". See also: "med ana schwoazzn tintn" (Artmann)

Comment: @vectory: I added an extra section especially for you (*Depperter*). I hope, this satisfies you more.

Comment: "Many of the adjectives listed above can be used to describe persons " name an adjective that can't! *Man is the measure of all things* (Protagoras, probably).

Comment: @vetory: A person can not be *luckert* (löchrig). *Zahnluckert* (ein unvollständiges Gebiss habend) is another word, but I never have heard that a person is called *luckert.* And *letschert* is only used for people in a figurative sense, much more often for lettuce and other other vegetables. Also *pickert* is more often used for a floor or a table covered with some sticky dirt.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, this is related to the German word "tappig" (https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/tappig). In fact, in some areas in Bavaria, "tappert" is used instead of "deppert".

A person who is "tappig" (unskillfull, having "two left hands") might appear to the bystanders as if it were also weak in his head.

Comment: I have never heard "tappig". Is it a variant of "tapsig"?

Comment: Likely related. See [here](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/tappig).

Comment: deppert und tapsig/tappert haben in meinem Sprachgefühl verschiedene Bedeutungen: ungefähr entspricht es dumm vs. ungeschickt als Synonyme

Comment: That isn't much more than a comment on what I already knew. Bayern's Dialekte Online (via Wörterbuchnetz) has *tappig*, points to *tapp* and Middle High German *tâpe*, which is onom. in origin as per Pfeifer, to whom I linked. The Duden Website you link has no useful etymology at all. Bayerisches Wörterbuch: *täppicht, -ig, -a* is interesting, “°i hab dappate Fin-ger”, which, needs to be said of course, does not match the glosses of "dumm, töricht, geistesgestört”, nor "dumm, ungeschickt" (col. 3.1224), @planetmaker. Interesting but no answer to my question.

Answer (score -2):

*D/Tappig, -icht, a*, *-s-ig* or *-ert* appear prima facie as arbitrary variants of adjectives to the same verb, *tappen*, which don't obtain different grammatical interpretations because the semantics are bleached beyond recognition and without an obvious relation to the verb.

https://publikationen.badw.de/de/bwb/-/3.1223.pdf

https://publikationen.badw.de/de/bwb/-/3.1225.pdf

https://publikationen.badw.de/de/bwb/-/3.1227.pdf

I shan't guess, for example, that *depp-ert* is correlated with French *-ard* as in *cunnus* / *conard*, reportedly from *-hard* as in *Bern(h)ard*, because, on the other hand, *concha* / *chat* would speak for *depp-icht, *deppat*.

Everyone agrees that *Depp* is the base, despite Grimm's not knowing the noun. Comparison to English *dope* is instructive.

> Meaning "foolish, stupid person" […] (1851) and may be from the notion of "thick-headed," later associated with the idea of "stupefied by narcotics."

(https://www.etymonline.com/word/dope#etymonline_v_13948)

The earliest recorded meaning of *dope*, 1807 in American English, is from Dutch *doop* "thick dipping sauce," (op.cit.)

This may be correlated with aisl. *þefja* "zerstoßen, stampfen (von Grütze)" in support of EWA, or with *zerdeppern* if related to *Topf* as follows.

Van der Sijs concurs that *doop* entered English through Dutch cuisine by the 19th century at the latest. Other dictionaries scarcely treat this term. Phillipa et al. focus mostly on the sense of dubbing, Ger. *Taufe*. The word is related to *deep* (etymologiebank.nl).

Incidently, German *Topf* is also explained by *tief* "diep" (Kluge, Pfeifer). But *tief* is not related to *tappen*. That the verb in some sense derived from obsolete *tâpe* "paw" by sound-symbolism is not verifiable because writing does not record sound, strictly speaking. However, *tupfen* "to immerse" (“kommt literatursprachlich im 18. Jh. außer Gebrauch, bleibt im Obd. jedoch erhalten." Pfeifer) had in fact many more connotations which make it quite similar to *tappen*, *antappen*, *zertappen*. English *tap* by the way, would formally correspond to *Zapfen*. Indeed, even the family of **tep-*, which EWA attenpted to split from **tap-*, does contain words meaning *deep*, *dive*, in the Wiktionary. The different sound correspondences are very confusing. Adelung specifically compared דבב "tappend einher gehen".

The theoretical problem seems to be the institution of baptism.

> Vaak wordt aangenomen dat de christelijke betekenis van het woord is ontstaan in het Gotisch. Bisschop Wulfila, die in de 4e eeuw de bijbel in het Gotisch vertaalde, gaf Grieks báptein ‘onderdompelen, dopen’ met daupjan weer. Deze betekenis zou dan **met de Gotische missie naar Beieren** (Duitsland) zijn gekomen en zich van daaruit over het vasteland van Europa hebben verbreid. De Engelsen en de Scandinaviërs gebruikten andere woorden: oe. fulwīan, letterlijk ‘volledig wijden’ en on. skíra, letterlijk ‘rein maken’ en kristna ‘kerstenen’. Het is de vraag **of de invloed van de Gotische missie werkelijk zo groot was**;

(“doop” in M. Philippa, F. Debrabandere, A. Quak, T. Schoonheim en N. van der Sijs (2003-2009) Etymologisch Woordenboek van het Nederlands, Amsterdam. https://etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/doop bold emphasis mine)

The influence of Christianity was not marginal. It has to be assumed that prior practices of forming group identity had involved tatooing, branding, an acid bath or a good old beating (cf. *zum Ritter schlagen* "to dub"). This is not recoverable.

The tangent would also be supported by **Ker(d)-* as a potential basis of the suffix, inasmuch as **Ker-* on the other hand is analogous to *dope-head*.

Yet it is not clear how this is a bad thing.

---

Other obvious options are to do with *Deibel*, or *dumm, tumb, doof, taub, benommen* etc. See also *daft*.